# Replace one cell with another depending on the contents in excel

Tags: excel

I have a very large excel list that requires replacing one cell with the contents of another depending on what the first cell is. The task could definitely be shortened if I could figure out how to automatically replace any cells with NULL in the contents with the contents of the cell to the right. Is there a formula that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

running this short macro:

```
Sub NULLfixer()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A20")
    For Each r In rng
        If InStr(1, r.Value, "NULL") > 0 Then
            r.Value = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]